# Adding hyperlinks to labels in certain cases, when dealing with databound repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, hyperlink, repeater

Sounds a bit cluttered, but basically I have a databound repeater.  On the ASP side, I have this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("uMessage") %>'></asp:Label>
```

I'm using the same template for 4 different datasets, and for 2 of them this should be a hyperlink and for the other 2 it shouldn't.  So, I'm guessing you have to add a hyperlink programmatically in the code-behind?  Has anyone ever done something like this?

Comment: On what basis do you decide to render hyperlink or label?

Comment: It depends solely on which dataset I'm binding.

Comment: to be clear, do you have one markup and bind any one of the four datasets to it? In the ondatabound event, can you know which dataset is bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way without all kinds of code-behind and therefor less code fragmentation, I would say you need a property that is set based on your condition prior to data binding.

```
protected bool LinkVisible { get; set; }
```

Then you just do this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("uMessage") %>' Visible="<%# !LinkVisible %>"></asp:Label>
<asp:HyperLink ID="Link" runat="server" Visible="<%# LinkVisible %>" ><%#Eval("uMessage") %></asp:HyperLink>
```

This sets the Visible for either the Label or the HyperLink. Visible false means it won't even get rendered. In your markup you can see that there will be a label or a hyperlink and no special things popup from the code behind.

You don't need to add the property LinkVisible, but can do the condition there too.

Comment: I decided to go this route and it worked well for what I was doing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible in code behind on DataItem bound

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label2");
        if (lbl.Text == "your condition")
        {
            HyperLink yourLink = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("yourID");
            yourLink.enabled = false;
        }
    }
```